# How to send long query string in Windows Phone with HttpWebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-7.1, query-string, windows-phone-8

I am making an API call to Facebook, using the Facebook C# SDK, and I can't seem to send long query strings via HTTP GET. I need a long FQL query (select .. from .. where .. in ) to execute and I can't seem to send it. If the query is smaller, it does send successfully and return the results. Unfortunatelly, as FQL supports GET and not POST, I am stuck to GET.

How can I increase the default query string limit in Windows Phone HttpWebRequest?

I am using Windows Phone SDK 7.1, but testing on Windows Phone 8 device.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to switch to http post (if possible) or optimize your request somehow.

Read [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url).  While the official standard for HTTP says that there should be no maximum, in reality [there are maximums](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html). For example, [IE have an upper bound of 2083 characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).  Windows Phone seems to have similar limit to IE.

> Microsoft Internet Explorer has a maximum uniform resource locator
>   (URL) length of 2,083 characters. Internet Explorer also has a maximum
>   path length of 2,048 characters. This limit applies to both POST
>   request and GET request URLs.
>
> If you are using the GET method, you are limited to a maximum of 2,048
>   characters, minus the number of characters in the actual path.
>
> However, the POST method is not limited by the size of the URL for
>   submitting name/value pairs. These pairs are transferred in the header
>   and not in the URL.
>
> RFC 2616, "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1," does not specify
>   any requirement for URL length.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/f96622fe-4dcb-4d38-8831-4cfad1aa4a06/